# How to use numpy/python to make a "chain reaction"?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to implement a "chain reaction". For example, for a 3x3 matrix all elements are initialized to zero, then one element (randomly) is assigned 1. A first iteration occurs and all the elements neighbouring 1 (up/down/left/right) gets changed from 0 -> 1. Now second iteration occurs and the process continues till all the elements in `a(1)` column become 1.

I have thought of using nested loops (for, for if, if elif..) but the code becomes kind of ugly (imo) and time consuming. I was wondering if this can be done with any other approach.

My Approach: Initialize with the help of `np.zeros`, then randomly assign any one element to 1.

```py
import numpy as np
from random import randint, choice
import time
    
n = int(input("Enter number of modes(n):"))
start = time.time()
m1 = [i+1 for i in range(n)] 
print(m1)

# initializing 
m = []
ones = [1,1,1,1,1]
for i in range(n):
    a = np.zeros(n)
    m.append(a)
    
m1 = choice(m)
A = randint(0, len(m1)-1)
B = randint(0, len(ones)-1)
    
m1[A]=ones[B]

# game begins here:  
print("----Initializing----")
     
print("1st iteration")
print(np.array(m))
```

Comment: The search term you are looking for is `flood fill`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `np.argwhere()` to get the indices of nonzero elements at each iteration. That way you don't need to go through the entire matrix at each iteration, but you will need to do some `if-else` checking to see if you're on a boundary.

```py
import numpy as np


def flood_fill_naive(n):
    A = np.zeros((n,n))     # Initialize an array of zeros.
    snapshots = []          # Copies of the matrix after each change.

    def fill_entry(i,j):
        """Set A[i,j] = 1 if (i,j) is a valid index pair for A."""
        if 0 <= i < A.shape[0] and 0 <= j < A.shape[1]:
            A[i,j] = 1
            snapshots.append(A.copy())

    # Fill in a single random entry to start.
    i,j = np.random.randint(A.shape)
    fill_entry(i,j)

    # Do the reaction until all entries are 1.
    while np.count_nonzero(A) != A.size:
        # Find the indices of nonzero elements.
        for i,j in np.argwhere(A):
            # Set 0 -> 1 on neighbors, except at boundaries.
            fill_entry(i-1,j)  # Up
            fill_entry(i,j-1)  # Left
            fill_entry(i,j+1)  # Right
            fill_entry(i+1,j)  # Down

    return snapshots


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input("Enter integer size of matrix: "))
    for snap in flood_fill_naive(n):
        print(snap)
```

But notice that this approach does a lot of repeat work. For example, the initial 1 only updates its neighbors once, and then you can forget about it. So at each step, you really only need to remember the spaces that were just updated, since they are the only ones that potentially have neighbors that are 0.

```
0 0 0 0 0       0 0 1 0 0       0 1 x 1 0       1 x x x 1
0 0 1 0 0       0 1 x 1 0       1 x x x 1       x x x x x
0 0 0 0 0  -->  0 0 1 0 0  -->  0 1 x 1 0  -->  1 x x x 1 --> ...
0 0 0 0 0       0 0 0 0 0       0 0 1 0 0       0 1 x 1 0
0 0 0 0 0       0 0 0 0 0       0 0 0 0 0       0 0 1 0 0
```

So let's just try to keep track of the indices of the "current 1s" and "previous 1s" (marked as x's above). In fact, what we're doing here is a breadth-first search. See [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [Flood Fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) on Wikipedia.

```py
def flood_fill_bfs(n): 
    A = np.zeros((n,n))        # Initialize an array of zeros.

    snapshots = []             # Copies of the matrix after each change.
    visit_queue = []           # List of indices to visit in the future. 
    visited = set()            # Set of indices already visited.

    def fill_entry(i,j):
        """If (i,j) has not been visited, visit it by setting A[i,j] = 1
        and adding it to the visit queue.
        """
        # Do nothing if this index has been visited. 
        if (i,j) in visited: 
            return
        # If the index has not been visited but is valid,
        if 0 <= i < A.shape[0] and 0 <= j < A.shape[1]: 
            A[i,j] = 1 
            visited.add((i,j)) 
            visit_queue.append((i,j)) 
            snapshots.append(A.copy()) 

    # Fill in a single random entry to start.
    i,j = np.random.randint(A.shape)
    fill_entry(i,j) 

    # Fill in neighbors of 1's until all entries are 1.
    while np.count_nonzero(A) != A.size:
        i,j = visit_queue.pop(0) 

        # Set 0 -> 1 on neighbors, except at boundaries. 
        fill_entry(i-1,j)  # Up 
        fill_entry(i,j-1)  # Left 
        fill_entry(i,j+1)  # Right 
        fill_entry(i+1,j)  # Down 

    return snapshots


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input("Enter integer size of matrix: "))
    for snap in flood_fill_bfs(n):
        print(snap)
```

You can guess which routine will be faster:

```
In [1]: %time _ = flood_fill_naive(100)                                               
CPU times: user 6.21 s, sys: 258 ms, total: 6.47 s
Wall time: 6.49 s

In [2]: %time _ = flood_fill_bfs(100)                                                 
CPU times: user 709 ms, sys: 310 ms, total: 1.02 s
Wall time: 1.03 s
```